# How to add Document with Custom ID to Firebase (Firestore) on Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to add a document to firestore collection with custom id on Swift Language, not the id generated by firestore engine.

Thanks in advance for your responses.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes. Just try this:

```
Firestore.firestore().collection("items").document("yourId").setData(["item": "test"])
```

Answer (score 1):

## 2020

Usually you'd want the error handling:

```
Firestore.firestore()
    .collection("companyAddress")
    .document(companyID)
    .setData([
        "address1": a1,
        "address2": a2,
        "city": c
    ]) { [weak self] err in
        guard let self = self else { return }
        if let err = err {
            print("err ... \(err)")
            self.yourErrorAlert()
        }
        else {
            print("saved ok")
            self.proceedWithUX()
        }
}
```

Comment: Error: Cannot assign value of type 'Void' to type 'DocumentReference'