# How to manage add and update data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Flutter.
I would like to add data at first. 
If email or uid had been registered, I want to update data01/02 or add data01/02.

How can I specify the initial data.

```
    _firestore.collection('members').add({
    'uid': loginUser.uid,
    'email': loginUser.email,
    'data01': {
        'name': name,
        'img_url': 'https://www.xxx.xxx/xxx.png',
        'data02': {
            'phone': phone,
        }
    }
```

Please give me advice.

Comment: How is your firebase 'members' collection structured?
This code is for adding a document. Before it you need to call Firebase to check whether your uid/email exists in your database. So you could wrap yours in a query where you look for matches.
Also, I would recommend you to use the userId as the name of your document, this way you will have a document per member and it would work fine with federated sign in.

Comment: It is hard to explain. `members` structure is as you see up code. I don't understand, but do you mean I should put same uid on document ID? I should not have use default Document ID?

Comment: I see. What you mean. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53583664/how-to-add-document-with-custom-id-to-firebase-firestore-on-swift

Comment: Yes. If you are able to modify the structure of your collection, the way to proceed might be easier, because a user will be always have a uid, you won't need to look by email, and just need to check if a document with uid name exists or not

Comment: However I got not to understand how to get snapshot from document ID. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you set your document name to your loginUser.uid you can use:

```dart
String rawJson = '{
    "email": loginUser.email,
    "data01": {
        "name": name,
        "img_url": "https://www.xxx.xxx/xxx.png",
        "data02": {
            "phone": phone,
        }
    }';

Map<String, dynamic> updateData = jsonDecode(rawJson); // import 'dart:convert';


final userDocument = await Firestore.instance.document('members/$loginUser.uid');
final userDocumentGet = userDocument.get().then((value) {
      if (value == null || !value.exists) {
      //a document for the member can NOT be found
      Firestore.instance.document('members/$loginUser.uid').setData(updateData);

    } else {
      //a document for the member is found
     Firestore.instance.document('members/$loginUser.uid').updateData(updateData);

    }
});
```