# Add nested data in Firestore by flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm from following issue.

[How to manage add and update data in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910157/how-to-manage-add-and-update-data-in-firebase/61920349#61920349)

Initially I can make data in firestore following code.

However I would like to add `car2` inside of `cars` after `car1`.
I have no idea of it.

```
_firestore.collection('members').document(${loginUser.uid}).setData({
    'cars': {
    'car1': {
        'name': name,
        'img_url': 'https://www.xxx.xxx/xxx.png',
        'details': {
            'type': carType,
        }
    }
  }
```

Please give me advice.

Comment: That is my typo. sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add `cars2`, then do the following:

```
_firestore.collection('members').document(${loginUser.uid}).updateData({
     "cars.car2": {
        'name': name,
        'img_url': 'https://www.xxx.xxx/xxx.png',
        'details': {
            'type': carType,
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Firestore.instance.collection(city).document('Attractions').updateData({"data": FieldValue.arrayUnion(obj)});
```

Comment: I don't get what obj is. Error comes out.

Comment: obj is array(List)