# How to get count of nested items in Firestore with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm from following issue again.

[Add nested data in Firestore by flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929827/add-nested-data-in-firestore-by-flutter/61930720#61930720)

I would like to know how many cars in this map in advance.
I need to numbering on car label to update(add) in this case.

```
'cars': {
    'car1': {
        'name': name,
        'img_url': 'https://www.xxx.xxx/xxx.png',
        'details': {
            'type': carType,
        }
    },
    'car2': {
        'name': name,
        'img_url': 'https://www.xxx.xxx/xxx.png',
        'details': {
            'type': carType,
        }
    }
}
```

In this case I want 2.
Or something better way? Please give me advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the `cars` map:

```
_firestore.collection('members').document(${loginUser.uid}).get().then((value){
      print(value.data);
      Map<String,dynamic> cars = value.data["cars"];
      print(cars.length);
    });
```

Retrieve the document, then use `length` property to get the number of elements inside the `cars` map.