# How to update the part of data without all data in Firebase with Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm from following issue.

[Add nested data in Firestore by flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61929827/add-nested-data-in-firestore-by-flutter/61929953?noredirect=1#comment109539603_61929953)

I would like to update only `car1 name` and `img_url`.
I succeed update `car1 name` and `img_url`. However `details` are disappeared without data.

I would like to know how to update the part of data.

```
_firestore.collection('members').document(${loginUser.uid}).updateData({
    'cars': {
    'car1': {
        'name': name,
        'img_url': 'https://www.xxx.xxx/xxx.png',
        'details': {
            'type': carType,
        }
    }
  }
```

How can I do that. Please give me advice. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried without passing "details"?

Comment: Yes, when I update there are no details. That is why I asked if I can update part of data without all.

Comment: one way is to get the whole data then tweak it locally and update it on firestore, whereas another one is to create a subdocument so you can change parts of data.

Comment: So you mean I need whole data when update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setData` with `merge:true`

```
_firestore.collection('members').document(${loginUser.uid}).setData({
'cars': {
  'car1': {
      'name': name,
      'img_url': 'https://www.xxx.xxx/xxx.png',
      }
    },
  },
  merge:true,
);
```

Comment: Do I need still details?

Comment: No it won't be required, It will just insert new data and merge the existing data.

Comment: That one I would like to do.

Comment: From your question, as far as I understood you want to update certain data and retain the existing data. For example here you wanted to update car1 name and image_url and retain the previous value of the details. I hope that's what you need.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you. But the another error is happened.

Comment: In answer of previous issue, I wrote like `"cars.car1": { 'name': name,`. But I should have written `"cars": {car1": { 'name': name,` . Already I figured out. Thank you.